# Suslin's Stability Theorem for Chevalley Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-k-theory

I am looking for a version of Suslin's Stability Theorem for Chevalley groups. 
The version of the theorem for $G=SL_n({\mathbb Z}[x_1, \dots , x_m])$ states that the if $n\ge m+2$, the elementary matrices generate $G$. I think by embedding many copies of $SL_n$, one can prove a similar statement, but probably with a bad bound, for all Chevalley groups over ${\mathbb Z}[x_1, \dots , x_m]$. I was wondering if a sharp bound has already been worked out in the literature.

Comment: It would be helpful to say more precisely what you mean by "embedding many copies ...."  Also, there are somewhat different versions of "Chevalley groups": adjoint type in Chevalley's original construction, but arbitrary type in Steinberg's lectures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am somewhat puzzled by your version of "Suslin stability theorem". What you are referring to is a combination of usual stabilization for $SK_1$ and an estimate for the stable rank of integer polynomials. Suslin's theorem states something much stronger, in particular Corollary 6.6 in his paper [On the structure of the special linear group over polynomial rings](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/izv/v41/i2/p235) is as follows (note that it doesn't depend on the number of variables):

> Let $A$ be a regular ring such that $SK_1(A)=0$ (for example, the ring of integers in an algebraic number field). Then $SL_r(A[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$ is generated by elementary matrices for $r\geqslant\max(3,\dim A+2)$.

Corollary 7.10 extends this result to rings of the form $A[x_1^\pm,\ldots,x_k^\pm,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n]$ for $A$ regular.

For other Chevalley groups the situation is complicated. One has the stability theorems for $K_1(\Phi)$ in terms of stable rank (or its ramifications such as absolute stable rank or $\Lambda$-stable rank), but they give pretty bad bounds for polynomial rings.

There is, however, the following version of Suslin's theorem for symplectic group in a paper [On symplectic groups over polynomial rings](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02571323) by F. Grunewald, J. Mennicke and L. Vaserstein:

> Let $A$ be a locally principal ring. For an integer $m\geqslant0$ put $R=A[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$. Then $Sp_{2n}(R)=Sp_{2n}(A)\cdot Ep_{en}(R)$ for any $n\geqslant2$.

By locally principal ring they mean a commutative ring such that its localization at any maximal ideal is a principal ideal ring.

For euclidean ring $A$ this gives $K_1(\mathsf{C}_\ell,R)=0$.

As a byproduct they also prove a stronger version of Suslin's theorem for $SL$ and a locally principal ring.

They also have a version for Laurent polynomial rings and claim that by using stability theorems for $K_1$ as in M. Stein's papers one can prove the same results for classical simple algebraic groups of relative rank $\geqslant2$, but the latter has never been written in full details.

**UPDATE 14.02.2019**
The proof for all simply-connected Chevalley groups is given by A. Stavrova in [Chevalley groups of polynomial rings over Dedekind domains](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04326). Namely, she proves the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a locally principal ring, and let $G$ be a Chevalley—Demazure group scheme of isotropic rank $\geq2$. Then $G(R[x_1,\ldots,x_n])=G(R)E(R[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$ for any $n\geq1$.

If $R$ is a Dedekind ring of arithmetic type (for example, $R=\mathbb{Z}$), it follows that $G(R[x_1,\ldots,x_n])=E(R[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$.

Comment: @Andrei Smolensky Great answer, but I was wondering if you knew whether Suslin's theorem applies to non-commutative regular rings, I.e. von Neumann regular or regular in the sense that it is Gorenstein with finite global and GK dimension

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what happens over $\mathbb{Z}$, but for reductive groups over a field, it turns out that there is no analogue to Suslin's theorem in general. Indeed consider the following result (due to A.Stavrova, Homotopy invariance of non-stable K_1-functors, http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4664):

For a split reductive group $G$ over a ring $R$, let me denote by $K^G_1(R)$ the quotient of $G(R)$ by the subgroup $E(R)$ of elementary matrices (defined via a Chevalley presentation, and which turns out to be a normal subgroup). Then for any field $k$, any $G$ such that any semi-simple normal subgroup of $G$ is of rank at least $2$ (e.g. $G$ simple of rank at least $2$) and any $n\geq 0$. Then 
$$
K_1^G(k[X_1,\ldots,X_n])\simeq K^G_1(k)
$$
So the obstruction for elementary matrices to generate is stable.

This does not contradict Suslin's result because, as is well-known, $K^{SL_n}_1(k)$ is trivial (as is the case for all semi-simple simply-connected split groups).

Comment: For Chevalley groups, however, the situation is better than for isotropic reductive groups in general. Namely, in a paper "Whitehead groups of Chevalley groups over polynomial rings" by E. Abe Corollary 1.9 states that for any ring $A$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{rank}}\Phi>1$ $K_1(\Phi,A[x])=0$ if and only if $K_1(\Phi,A)=0$. This result is actually referred to on the first page of the paper by Stavrova you mentioned.

Comment: Actualy, what I wrote above is incorrect. The theorem states that $K_1(\Phi,A[x])=0$ if and only if $K_1(\Phi,A)=0$ and $K_1(\Phi,A[x],xA[x])=0$. Not sure what happens if one drops the assumption on relative $K_1$.