# Is SL(n,Z[x]) generated by transvections?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-k-theory, matrix-theory

Is $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}[x])$ equal to $E(n,\mathbb{Z}[x])$, the subgroup generated by transvections?

Comment: The answer to the question is clearly "no", since the determinant is not trivial on $GL_n$. But the answer to the question in the title is yes, as least when $n$ is big enough, and this follows (maybe there are more simple methods) from the fact that it works for $SL(\infty,\mathbf Z)$, from the fundamental theorem of K-theory applied to SK1, and from stability results on the homology of $SL_n$. Probably you would find the exact answer in Rosenberg's Algebraic K-Theory book. Once again, there might also exist an elementary answer.

Comment: But $GL(n,Z[x])$ is just matrices with determinant $1$ or $-1$, so it should be true for both, no?

Comment: Also, this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156563/suslins-stability-theorem-for-chevalley-groups seems to answer my question in the affirmative for $ n =1,3,4...$.

Comment: Just to be sure : do you know of transvections that have determinant $-1$ ? That would imply that we don't have the same definition. The link you give, indeed, contains an answer to the question in the title and seems to imply that $SL_n(\mathbf Z[T])=E_n(\mathbf Z[T])$ for $n\geq 3$. I don't know what happens for $n=2$, but that has certainly been studied (by Bass ?)

Comment: Found ! Grunewald, Mennicke, and Vaserstein [ On the groups SL2(Z[x]) and SL2(k[x, y]), Israel Jour. Math.
86, (1994) 157–193 ] show that $SL_2(\mathbf Z[T])/E_2(\mathbf Z[T])$ surject on free groups with countable ranks !

Comment: Cohn was probably the first to prove that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[T]) \neq \mathrm{E}_2(\mathbf{Z}[T])$. A concrete example of a matrix not in $\mathrm{E}_2$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1+2T & 4 \cr -T^2 & 1-2T\end{bmatrix}$. I took this example from Lam's "Serre's problem on projective modules", rk 8.11.

Comment: Why was this downvoted and closed?  It's a perfectly reasonable question with a nontrivial answer.  Was this an overreaction to the OP's minor mistake of typing $GL$ instead of $SL$ in the body of the question?

Comment: Note that the term "transvection" means a more general type of elements, namely an element of the form $e+uv$, where $u$ is a column, $v$ is a row and $vu=0$. Over a (skew-)field they are exactly the conjugates of the elementary transvections $e+\xi e_{ij}$, but in general not every transvection lies in the elementary subgroup. That does not affect your question, of course, but for other rings it might.

Comment: Hi all! I wished to "show" that if $ A, B\in \mathbb{Z}[x]^{n\times n}$ and if $ A \sim B$, in the sense that there are matrices $ P, Q \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z}[x]) $ such that $ PAQ = B $, then, there is a sequence of row and column operations that converts $ A $ into $ B $ (which are adding a multiple of one row(column) to another row(column),switching two rows (columns) and multiplying a row(column) by a unit i.e.1,-1). It seems this is not true for $ n = 2 $, but true for $ n \geq 3 $. This is what I actually wanted. Can someone give a list of references that I can use to quote the full result?

Comment: @swaqar:  Your most recent comment repeats the error that I corrected in your original post (and that led to this question's being closed for a while).  Clearly if $P=-Q$ is the identity, what you're asking for is impossible.  You want $SL$, not $GL$.

Comment: Hi Steven! Can we discuss this in a private chat?

Comment: @swaqar:  My mistake.  I see you included "multiplying a row by a unit" as an allowable operation.  Given that, your comment is fine.

Comment: Thank you Steven! So, what reference should I give for this result in my paper? I don't know K-Theory at all, and I am trying to look into some K-Theory books, but I have not been able to find the exact result.So,
first of all, is the result of $ n \geq 3 $ actually true? Second, which reference could I use for it?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg and upvoters of his comment: because not everybody was able to guess the correct meaning (GL instead of SL was one thing, "generated by the group" was confusing though not incorrect). Also I have seen in MO several questions where an apparently naive question was very close to a natural and more interesting one, and people tend to interpret it as the corrected question but the author insisted that it was really the naive one (here I mean naive at a research level). In its original formulation it was clear to me that the question had to be closed (or clarified by its author).

Answer (score 7):

First, for $n=2$, the result is certainly false by the counterexample of Cohn quoted in Oblomov's comment.

For higher $n$, start with the fact that the Bass Stable Rank of a commutative ring is at most 1 more than the Krull dimension.  (I'm sure you can find this hidden in Chapter V of Bass's book on K-theory, though extracting it might require some work to get familiar with his notation).  Therefore ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ has stable rank at most 3.  In fact, it's almost surely exactly 3.  (There is some discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132839/bass-stable-range-of-mathbf-zx) about whether this stable rank might in fact be 2, but there's something close to a proof there that this is not the case.)

Now from Bass, Chapter V, 3.3, it follows that for all $n\ge 4$, we have
$$GL_n({\bf Z}[x])=GL_3({\mathbb Z}[X])E_n({\mathbb Z}[X])$$

In other words, for any matrix of size $4x4$ or greater, you can, by applying elementary operations, reduce to a matrix of the form 
$$\pmatrix{A&0\cr 0&I\cr}$$

where $A$ is 3 by 3 and $I$ is the $(n-3)\times (n-3)$ identity matrix.

It's not immediately clear to me how much better you can do, but I bet either that Wilberd van der Kallen (who shows up here occasionally) or Vaserstein (who I think does not) could answer this in his sleep.  You might want to email one or both of them.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I found Suslin's original paper, and indeed, the Corollary 6.6, as claimed in the first answer in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156563/suslins-stability-theorem-for-chevalley-groups is indeed applicable to $ \mathbb{Z}[x]$, with $ n \geq 3 $, since $ \mathbb{Z} $ is regular, $ SK_{1}(Z) = 0 $ and Krull Dimension of $ \mathbb{Z} $ is $ 1 $.

Comment: You are right --- Suslin's paper supercedes the content of my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: the conclusion of the discussion you mention about the stable range of $\mathbf Z [x]$ was that it is indeed of stable range $3$. It is proven in the paper by Grunewald, Mennicke, and Vaserstein mentionned by "few_reps" as indicated in the discussion.